# numpy: apply an arbitrary function to array element

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, ip-address

```
import pandas as pd
from ipaddr import IPv4Address

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'192.168.1.10', '45.7.12.34', 'abc'],[4, '10.10.1.11', '90.90.67.33', 'def'], [77, '52.1.7.90', '67.5.3.5', 'ghi' ], [90, '19.19.90.7', '77.88.99.44', 'xyz']], columns=['A', 'sip', 'dip', 'location'])

addrs = [(int)(IPv4Address(addr)) for addr in df[['sip', 'dip']].values.flatten().tolist()]
```

I'm wondering if there is a `numpy` native way to apply a function to each element of array before converting to the list?

Comment: There is a `np.frompyfunc`, but its performance is comparable to a list comprehension, especially if the result is supposed to be a list (as opposed to new object dtype array).  As long as your function has to be called once for each element, the iteration/accumulation mechanism doesn't make much difference in time.

Answer (score 1):

With pandas (since it is tagged) can you also try [`series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) from vanilla python:

```
[*map(int,df[['sip', 'dip']].stack().map(IPv4Address))]
#or list(map(int,df[['sip', 'dip']].stack().map(IPv4Address)))
#or df[['sip', 'dip']].stack().map(IPv4Address).astype('int64').tolist()
```

---

```
[3232235786,
 755436578,
 168427787,
 1515864865,
 872482650,
 1124401925,
 320035335,
 1297638188]
```